# Regex not working in zul -ZK

Tags: java, regex, zk, zul

I'm working with Java and ZK. Trying to use a regex as a constraint on a textbox.

This is the regex: `^[0-9]{1,9}(?:\\.[0-9]{1,3})?$`.
It is working fine in Java but while using in zul `textbox`, its giving error: `Unknown constraint: ^[0-9]{1`
Please have a look at the screenshot attached:

[image]

Valid values of regex-

```
121245.121(3 digits after decimal is valid)
2145.11
0.23
5748579
```

Invalid values-

```
.111
45445.454545(3 digits after decimal is valid)
-1545.2
22..
```

Code in zul is as below-

```
<textbox xmlns:w="client" id="bal" maxlength="12" tooltiptext="Balance" constraint="^[0-9]{1,9}(?:\\.[0-9]{1,3})?$">
```

ZK Fiddler can be found at : http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2c9e93q/2-Textbox-regex-issue

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RC. mentions in the answer above, the ***regex delimiters*** (`/<pattern>/`) are required in the `pattern` attribute value to define a regex. However, your regex will allow values like `67\k78` because the `\\` defines a literal backslash and a dot stands for any character but a newline.

The correct regex is

```
<textbox constraint="/^[0-9]{1,9}(?:[.][0-9]{1,3})?$/" xmlns:w="client" id="bal" maxlength="12" tooltiptext="Balance">
                     ^              ^^^             ^
```

Note that no escaping is necessary when the dot is placed into a character class `[.]`.

See the [updated fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/17tkvtp/1-Textbox-regex-issue).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fix the regexp (it seems it's not working), but to use your regexp in a constraint you have to enclose it between <kbd>/</kbd>:

```
<textbox xmlns:w="client" id="bal" maxlength="12" tooltiptext="Balance" 
         constraint="/^[0-9]{1,9}(?:\\.[0-9]{1,3})?$/"/>
```

demo: http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2bcm8bj/2-Textbox-regex-issue

---

From the [doc](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Guide/ZUL_Components/Form_and_Inputs/Input_Controls#Constraints):

> To specify a regular expression, you may have to use the character /
>   to enclose the regular expression as follows. 
>   `<textbox constraint="/.+@.+\.[a-z]+/"/>`